# Why is this declaration not compatible?

Tags: php, oop

In short I have

```
abstract class AbstractMapper implements MapperInterface {

    public function fetch(EntityInterface $entity, Array $conditions = array()) {
        . . .
    }

}

interface MapperInterface {

    public function fetch(EntityInterface $entity, Array $conditions = array());

}

abstract class AbstractUserMapper extends AbstractMapper implements UserMapperInterface {

    public function fetch(UserInterface $user, Array $conditions = array()) {

        $conditions = array_merge($conditions, array('type' => $user->getType()));

        return parent::fetch($user, $conditions);
    }

}

interface UserMapperInterface {

    public function fetch(UserInterface $user, Array $conditions = array());

}
```

This is the error I get:

Fatal error: Declaration of Model\Data\Mappers\AbstractUserMapper::fetch() must be compatible with that of Model\Data\Mappers\Interfaces\MapperInterface::fetch()

If I change the `UserInterface` to `EntityInterface` it works but it just seems wrong and also in my `AbstractUserMapper::fetch()` when I type`$user` my IDE shows only the methods declared in my `EntityInterface` and `getType()` is not in that list.

I know I can still put `$user->getType()` because I know the object I have implements the `UserInterface` but it all just seems wrong, even my IDE thinks so or am I missing something here?

Why does this not work? It is messing up my code if I have to put `EntityInterface` instead of '`UserInterface` I think.

Comment: It could be because your AbstractUserMapper extends AbstractMapper but your fetch() functions don't match up. Maybe try adding a fetchUser() method instead of the same function name

Comment: An interface is a contract about what you support, you cannot say _"the first argument is a `EntityInterface` AND the first argument is a `UserInterface`."_. You either expect/require the first argument to have the `EntityInterface` capabilities, or the `UserInterface` capabilities. The fact of the matter is, if you _need_ `UserInterface`'s in `AbstractUserMapper::fetch()`, then it simply _does not implement `MapperInterface::fetch()`_, as it would have to be able to deal with _any_ `EntityInterface`, not just `UserInterface` ones...

Comment: Wouldn't you then think that if the UserInterface extends EntityInterface that it would then let me do what I want to do because it would know that UserInterface also has the capabilities of EntityInterface and there should be no problems as far as I can see. Is this just a PHP thing?

Comment: PHP does not support method overloading... only method overridding so you cannot have more then one method on a class with a given name, which is what you would have to have to meet the requirements of both of the interfaces.

Comment: To illustrate it perhaps: you are running a TV repair shop, that advertises _"we can fix any TV"_, after which you proceed to require that people give you only plasma tvs, because you cannot work with the rest. The slogan _"we can fix any tv"_ no longer holds true, you can only fix plasma tvs and should advertise as such.

Comment: As @Orangepill said. It's a dynamic typed language so no method overloading here. Which is not cool... but we have to put up with! :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies here:

```
abstract class AbstractUserMapper 
  extends AbstractMapper 
  implements UserMapperInterface
```

As the first step, inspect the definition of `AbstractMapper`:

```
abstract class AbstractMapper 
  implements MapperInterface
```

Interface definitions between parent and child classes are transitive, so we can merge the first definition:

```
abstract class AbstractUserMapper 
  extends AbstractMapper 
  implements UserMapperInterface, MapperInterface
```

This means that your class needs to implement:

```
public function fetch(EntityInterface $entity, Array $conditions = array());

public function fetch(UserInterface $user, Array $conditions = array());
```

And this is not possible, because method overloading doesn't exist in PHP.

**Possible solution**

Assuming the following interface definitions:

```
interface EntityInterface {}
interface UserInterface extends EntityInterface {}
```

I would suggest to drop the `implements UserMapperInterface`:

```
abstract class AbstractUserMapper extends AbstractMapper
```