# Type hinting child interface

Tags: interface, parent-child, php, type-hinting

I have a problem with type hinting. I have classes like this (pseudocode):

```
interface iBaseDAO
{
    public function __construct(iBaseDataMapper $objDataMapper);
    //...
}

interface iBaseDataMapper
{
    //...
}

interface iConcreteDataMapper extends iBaseDataMapper
{
    //...
}

class ConcreteDAO implements iBaseDAO
{
    public function __construct(iConcreteDataMapper $objDataMapper)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I want to achieve, that `DAO` can be instantiated only with some kind of `DataMapper` but for `ConcreteDAO` be sure that it will be instantiated only with `ConcreteDataMapper`.
Since `iConcreteDataMapper` is child of `iBaseDataMapper` I think it should work, but I get error:

```
Fatal error: Declaration of ConcreteDAO::__construct() must be compatible with iBaseDAO::__construct(iBaseDataMapper $objDataMapper)
```

Why I cannot use `iConcreteDataMapper` in `ConcreteDAO`?
Thank you for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this declaration not compatible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662562/why-is-this-declaration-not-compatible)

Comment: Which part of the error message is hard for your to understand?